# Unable to install any application in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dpkg, dropbox

I'm facing below error while installing **any** application.

*E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.*

I tried to use `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then it resumed the Dropbox downloading, which I cancelled yesterday and rebooted laptop after that. I think Ubuntu is still stuck there. Is there any way to clear Dropbox downloading or to get rid of the above error.

Thanks

Comment: Downloading is stuck at 5%, it's not moving since last 15-20 mins.

Hey, Seems I've enough points to live chat, but don't know how to initiate it, Can you please start chat or help me in that way ?

That will be quick. Thanks

Comment: reboot then sudo dpkg --configure -a then sudo apt-get autoremove packagename then sudo apt-get update then install another app to check if the problem is only with this package if the other package is stuck too comment & edit your question

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge dropbox
```

Same goes for any package that tries to get its content from the net - flash, m$ fonts, skype...

Comment: here is the o/p of `sudo apt-get purge dropbox`

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Comment: @Tim I tried 3 different method's from that link, but still problem is there. :(

Comment: Try a restart ?

Comment: Reboot DONE. Still problem is there.